# latex installation on Suse Linux

Tags: installing, linux

I was working with latex on windows. I was using miktex and texmaker.

Unfortunately I had to change my OS and now I am working on Suse linux, which is a pretty new OS for me.

I have not seen a document or guide which explains the installation clearly, so I am in search for any help regarding the installation steps.

As per suggestions I am referring to [Installation guide](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) for the texlive installation.

I dont know how to use the mirrors and how to do the zypper install.

EDIT 1: I tried with the install-tl and it fails everytime after running for nearly 2 hours.

Here is the log:

```
Automated TeX Live installation using profile: installation.profile
Trying to verify cryptographic signatures!
Loading http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2016 from: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
Platform: x86_64-linux => 'GNU/Linux on x86_64'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
Using URL: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
Directory for temporary files: /tmp/9V0exB3E4u
Installer revision: 41646
Database revision: 42599
Settings:
  TEXDIR: "/usr/local/texlive/2016"
  TEXMFCONFIG: "~/.texlive2016/texmf-config"
  TEXMFHOME: "~/texmf"
  TEXMFLOCAL: "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local"
  TEXMFSYSCONFIG: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config"
  TEXMFSYSVAR: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var"
  TEXMFVAR: "~/.texlive2016/texmf-var"
  binary_amd64-freebsd: "0"
  binary_amd64-netbsd: "0"
  binary_armel-linux: "0"
  binary_armhf-linux: "0"
  binary_i386-cygwin: "0"
  binary_i386-freebsd: "0"
  binary_i386-linux: "0"
  binary_i386-netbsd: "0"
  binary_i386-solaris: "0"
  binary_powerpc-linux: "0"
  binary_sparc-solaris: "0"
  binary_universal-darwin: "0"
  binary_win32: "0"
  binary_x86_64-cygwin: "0"
  binary_x86_64-darwin: "0"
  binary_x86_64-linux: "1"
  binary_x86_64-solaris: "0"
  collection-basic: "1"
  collection-bibtexextra: "1"
  collection-binextra: "1"
  collection-context: "1"
  collection-fontsextra: "1"
  collection-fontsrecommended: "1"
  collection-fontutils: "1"
  collection-formatsextra: "1"
  collection-games: "1"
  collection-genericextra: "1"
  collection-genericrecommended: "1"
  collection-htmlxml: "1"
  collection-humanities: "1"
  collection-langafrican: "1"
  collection-langarabic: "1"
  collection-langchinese: "1"
  collection-langcjk: "1"
  collection-langcyrillic: "1"
  collection-langczechslovak: "1"
  collection-langenglish: "1"
  collection-langeuropean: "1"
  collection-langfrench: "1"
  collection-langgerman: "1"
  collection-langgreek: "1"
  collection-langindic: "1"
  collection-langitalian: "1"
  collection-langjapanese: "1"
  collection-langkorean: "1"
  collection-langother: "1"
  collection-langpolish: "1"
  collection-langportuguese: "1"
  collection-langspanish: "1"
  collection-latex: "1"
  collection-latexextra: "1"
  collection-latexrecommended: "1"
  collection-luatex: "1"
  collection-mathscience: "1"
  collection-metapost: "1"
  collection-music: "1"
  collection-omega: "1"
  collection-pictures: "1"
  collection-plainextra: "1"
  collection-pstricks: "1"
  collection-publishers: "1"
  collection-texworks: "1"
  collection-wintools: "0"
  collection-xetex: "1"
  doc_splitting_supported: "1"
  in_place: "0"
  inst_platform: "x86_64-linux"
  n_collections_available: "47"
  n_collections_selected: "46"
  n_systems_available: "17"
  n_systems_selected: "1"
  option_adjustrepo: "1"
  option_autobackup: "1"
  option_backupdir: "tlpkg/backups"
  option_desktop_integration: "1"
  option_doc: "1"
  option_file_assocs: "1"
  option_fmt: "1"
  option_letter: "0"
  option_menu_integration: "1"
  option_path: "0"
  option_post_code: "1"
  option_src: "1"
  option_sys_bin: "/usr/local/bin"
  option_sys_info: "/usr/local/share/info"
  option_sys_man: "/usr/local/share/man"
  option_w32_multi_user: "1"
  option_write18_restricted: "1"
  portable: "0"
  selected_scheme: "scheme-full"
  src_splitting_supported: "1"
  this_platform: "x86_64-linux"
  total_size: "0"
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2016
Installing [0001/3343, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0002/3343, time/total: 00:03/04:50:57]: 2up [66k]
Installing [0003/3343, time/total: 00:04/05:30:21]: Asana-Math [482k]
Installing [0004/3343, time/total: 00:07/04:36:07]: ESIEEcv [137k]
Installing [0005/3343, time/total: 00:09/05:09:16]: FAQ-en [4971k]
Installing [0006/3343, time/total: 00:18/01:48:36]: GS1 [1100k]
Installing [0007/3343, time/total: 00:22/01:52:16]: HA-prosper [266k]
Installing [0008/3343, time/total: 00:25/02:02:59]: IEEEconf [188k]
Installing [0009/3343, time/total: 00:28/02:14:20]: IEEEtran [1323k]
Installing [0010/3343, time/total: 00:32/02:10:43]: MemoirChapStyles [739k]
Installing [0011/3343, time/total: 00:34/02:08:15]: SIstyle [338k]
Installing [0012/3343, time/total: 00:37/02:14:51]: SIunits [284k]
Installing [0013/3343, time/total: 00:40/02:21:45]: Tabbing [217k]
Installing [0014/3343, time/total: 00:43/02:29:14]: Type1fonts [516k]
Installing [0015/3343, time/total: 00:45/02:28:52]: a0poster [119k]
Installing [0016/3343, time/total: 00:47/02:33:49]: a2ping [48k]
Installing [0017/3343, time/total: 00:48/02:36:25]: a2ping.x86_64-linux [1k]
Installing [0018/3343, time/total: 00:49/02:39:41]: a4wide [133k]
Installing [0019/3343, time/total: 00:50/02:41:01]: a5comb [91k]
Installing [0020/3343, time/total: 00:52/02:46:08]: aastex [1214k]
Installing [0021/3343, time/total: 00:56/02:41:41]: abbr [4k]
Installing [0022/3343, time/total: 00:56/02:41:38]: abc [288k]
Installing [0023/3343, time/total: 00:59/02:46:30]: abntex2 [4455k]
Installing [0024/3343, time/total: 01:06/02:18:25]: abraces [197k]
Installing [0025/3343, time/total: 01:08/02:21:01]: abstract [154k]
Installing [0026/3343, time/total: 01:10/02:23:54]: abstyles [151k]
Installing [0027/3343, time/total: 01:12/02:26:46]: academicons [95k]
Installing [0028/3343, time/total: 01:14/02:30:03]: accanthis [653k]
Installing [0029/3343, time/total: 01:17/02:30:39]: accfonts [37k]
Installing [0030/3343, time/total: 01:19/02:34:15]: accfonts.x86_64-linux [1k]
Installing [0031/3343, time/total: 01:19/02:34:15]: achemso [895k]
Installing [0032/3343, time/total: 01:23/02:34:38]: acmart [6180k]
Installing [0033/3343, time/total: 01:32/02:10:12]: acmconf [111k]
Installing [0034/3343, time/total: 01:35/02:13:52]: acro [594k]
Installing [0035/3343, time/total: 01:37/02:13:37]: acronym [282k]
Installing [0036/3343, time/total: 01:40/02:16:18]: acroterm [160k]
Installing [0037/3343, time/total: 01:42/02:18:12]: active-conf [327k]
Installing [0038/3343, time/total: 01:45/02:20:33]: actuarialangle [3k]
Installing [0039/3343, time/total: 01:46/02:21:52]: addfont [105k]
Installing [0040/3343, time/total: 01:48/02:24:00]: addlines [142k]
Installing [0041/3343, time/total: 01:50/02:25:55]: adfathesis [151k]
Installing [0042/3343, time/total: 01:52/02:27:45]: adforn [388k]
Installing [0043/3343, time/total: 01:55/02:29:36]: adfsymbols [401k]
Installing [0044/3343, time/total: 01:58/02:31:20]: adhocfilelist [30k]
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Then I tried with `"install-tl --profile installation.profile"` and it runs again for few hours and fails. Does the problem lies in the mirror ? can anyone confirm.

I did clean the old installation before running the new one.

I tried with yast installation as per [This link](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive-latex), but it throws error like "uninstallable providers:texlive:luatex-2013.......etc"

EDIT 2: Adding OS information

```
NAME="SLED"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 SP2"
ID="sled"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sled:12:sp2"
```

Comment: Either use upstream's installer for TeX Live (recommended but more initial effort) or use your distro's package manager to install it (more headaches later on, probably older software).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000 (adapt for other distros). Download and instructions: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html.

Comment: That's just a download error. Try again later or change the mirror you're using. I've never used an installation profile, but the problem just seems to be the download.

Comment: You probably don't need to clean before retrying. It will pick up where it left off and avoid downloading stuff twice, if you let it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux systems the administrator is called »root«. If you can, start Yast, which needs root's password. Install texlive from the package manager of Yast. Suses texlive is very well maintained.

Suses central package repo should provide texmaker as editor as well (at least it is on Tumbleweed). But if you feel adventurous some day, try Kile, which is KDE's LaTeX editor.

So it all boils down to the question, whether you are allowed to start Yast. If not, you'd have to install texlive itself locally (into ~/texmf ). But I can't recommend that to you. My advise is to install Suse's texlive packages, the maintainer Dr. Fink does a very good job.

To this end: YaST > Software > Software Management, search for 'texlive' and install the package with the simple name 'texlive'. I have no idea, how huge the download may be. But even with the vanilla texlive you have to install a lot of bytes...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with Yast, but it doesnt have any packages called texlive. I searched with different modes but no help. I am not aware of central package repository, can you please tell a bit about that.

Comment: Can you give some information about the OS you are using? Edit your question and add the result of this command in a terminal: `cat /etc/os-release`. Because there are many Suse OS versions available...

Comment: I have added the OS information. Can you please tell me a method which doesn't download everything and takes huge time. I mean it would be better for me to install basic packages and once the installation of texlive and texmaker is done, I would like to install the other necessary packages on the go.

Comment: I would recommend installing vanilla rather than your distro's packages, even if they are well-maintained. In the end, it makes life simpler @statisticalbeginner. (But you can always change your mind later, of course and starting this way is probably quicker.)